# vectorized operations is not efficient?

Tags: performance-tuning

Consider the following example:

```
4.*Mean@Table[ Boole[Random[]^2 + Random[]^2 < 1], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.408023, 3.14105}*)

With[{n = 10^6},
  4. Mean@Boole@Thread[(RandomReal[1, n]^2 + RandomReal[1, n]^2) < 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.460084, 3.14276}*)
```

I expected the second method to be more efficient since it used vectorized operations, but it works slowly, and I don't know why.  Is it possible to make it faster?
I used Mathematica 9 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the old `Random` function uses an inferior PRN generator and should not be used other than for legacy compatibility, if I recall correctly.

On my machine (version 7, Windows 7) the second method *is* faster than the first, though not by a great amount:

```
4.*Mean@Table[Boole[RandomReal[]^2 + RandomReal[]^2 < 1], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming

With[{n = 10^6}, 
  4. Mean@Boole@Thread[(RandomReal[1, n]^2 + RandomReal[1, n]^2) < 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.2840735, 3.14154}
>
> {0.4570262, 3.1401}

Numeric methods will be much faster:

```
With[{n = 10^6},
 With[{r = RandomReal[1, n]^2 + RandomReal[1, n]^2},
  4. * Mean[1 - UnitStep[r - 1]]
 ]
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0510029, 3.14232}

This is partly because the array is not unpacked, as it is in your code as can be seen by first running `On["Packing"]`:

```
On["Packing"]

With[{n = 10^6}, 
  4. Mean@Boole@Thread[(RandomReal[1, n]^2 + RandomReal[1, n]^2) < 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Less. >>
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000} to level 1. >>

Comment: "First, the old `Random` function uses an inferior PRN generator and should not be used other than for legacy compatibility, if I recall correctly." - right, the old Marsaglia-Zaman method (which is now also available with `SeedRandom[seed, Method -> "Legacy"]`) has been shown to be statistically inferior to the current default method. The OP might also consider switching to a different PRNG if need be, using also `SeedRandom[]`.

Comment: Thank you. Is this right? `With[{n = 10^6}, 
 With[{r = RandomReal[1, n]^2 + RandomReal[1, n]^2}, 
  4.*Mean[UnitStep[1 - r]]]]`

Comment: @explorer I believe you are asking: is `UnitStep[1 - r]` equivalent to `1 - UnitStep[r - 1]`?  Not precisely, because of the case of `1`: `{UnitStep[1 - r], 1 - UnitStep[r - 1]} /. r -> 1`.  It is unlikely to make a difference in your application however, IMHO, but to be rigorous I used the longer form.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks again for being so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Can't compete with Mr Wizard, but here's a vectorized version that's not too shabby:

```
n = 10^6;
-Mean[Sign@Clip[Total[RandomReal[1, {2, n}]^2] - 1, {-100, 0}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.133305, 3.14322}